# Add rows to gridview via JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Just having a start with JQuery, I have a webform where there is a

1. Drop down list with numbers numbers 1,2,3 as items
2. A gridview on the form (with text boxes on each row for taking inputs)
3. If user selects 2 in dropdown list, 2 rows get added to the gridview with a textbox on each row

Currently I'm doing this with UpdatePanel & gridview server side. How do I do this with JQuery ?

Should I skip the gridview altogether and just drop a table on my webform & add rows to it via JQuery ?

How would I add the server side textboxes on each row ? Is there an easy alternate.

Thank you, Damien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at [.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Comment: I am trying prepend on an empty gridview initially but it does not work. Can you give a little hint ?

Comment: $('#btnTest').click(function(){
          
  $('#<%=myGridView.ClientID%>').append("<tr>New row</tr>");
        });

Comment: place your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){//your code here});`

Comment: Thanks Enigma my code is already inside document.ready function but it won't work.

Comment: The code works when there is a row in the gridview but not on a zero rows.